# Updating Member preferences for one member group resets other member groups

Tags: members, config

I'm running 2.6.1 (can't update right now)
I have 2 member groups (+ admin)

Each time I update the channel publishing preferences the preferences of the other channel all revert to no access.

Is there a config file for member prefs or DB table I can edit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
I was searching the wrong thing, turns out it was 2.5.3 and this was the solution:

[Changing channel assignments for one member group disables them for other member groups](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5408/changing-channel-assignments-for-one-member-group-disables-them-for-other-member?rq=1)